# Why Mathematica says notebook "has changed outside of Mathematica" when saving to text file?

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, save

I wanted to export the notebook to plain text file. Given notebook `foo.nb`, I noticed each time I save the notebook to `foo.txt`, then when saving `foo.nb`, a message is then displayed saying the notebook was modified outside of Mathematica !

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is a little annoying message, since I did not change the notebook from outside of Mathematica. Is this message known to exist? Should Mathematica generate such message? Why does it generate such a message?  This message does not show up when saving the notebook to PDF file for example.

Here is small movie. This is using 11.2, on windows 7 home edition.

Steps to reproduce:
1. open notebook.
2. File->Save as -> select plain text.
3. Now do File->Save  to save current notebook. The message will pop-up

[image]